# Access isolated storage on an app that isn't mine

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, isolatedstorage

Trying to access the isolated storage for an mp3 downloader app on my Windows Phone 8.1 Dev Preview.  For CLI, I used the ISETool.exe that is included with the Windows Phone SDK.  Because I don't have the app's Product ID, I couldn't copy it's storage.  I think I got the product ID from the windowsphone.com store, but there's nothing to verify it against.  Additionally, I tried using the IsoStoreSpy tool, which won't list the app, it only lists my apps that I have created.

Anybody have input as to copying the isolated storage of an app I got from the store?

Edit: Device is dev unlocked

Answer (score 0):

You can only get files from side-loaded apps (eg, ones you deploy from VS). You can't extract files from Store-delivered apps.